# c++ recursion that i don't understand

Tags: c++, recursion

I don't understand why this returns a 5 when 5 is entered?
does it return a 1 each time the function can make a subtraction? and then add all those ones?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int Fibonacci(int);
int Fibonacci(int x)
{
    if (x == 0) return 0;  // Stopping conditions
    if (x == 1) return 1;
    return Fibonacci(x - 1) + Fibonacci(x - 2);
}
int main() {
    int num;
    cin >> num;
    cout << Fibonacci(num) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: You stopping condition returns a wrong result for the indexing you want

Comment: @StoryTeller the stopping condition makes sense the index is zero based but a sub zero is zero, not one. A sub one is 1 and so is a sub 2, which means a sub five is 5 as it should be.

Comment: @JeremyKahan, I know it's correct for 0-based indexing, but the OP expects results for 1-based indexing, hence my comment.

Answer (score 1):

For clarity, using a function

```
auto F( int x )
    -> int
{ return (x <= 1? x : F(x-2)+F(x-1)); }
```

F(5)
→ F(3) + F(4)
→ (F(1) + F(2)) + F(4)
→ (1 + F(2)) + F(4)
→ (1 + (F(0) + F(1))) + F(4)
→ (1 + (0 + F(1))) + F(4)
→ (1 + (0 + 1)) + F(4)
→ (1 + 1) + F(4)
→ 2 + F(4)
→ 2 + (F(2) + F(3))
and so on…

Comment: Unrelated question. Can't the return type be inferred from `x`? Or is the recursive call leaving us no choice but to mention the trailing return type?

Comment: The return type can indeed be inferred. I just prefer explicit where that's practical. I think it makes the code easier to read, and it guards against editing changing the *intended* return type.

Answer (score 0):

0,1,1,2,3,5 are what it calculates for getting to the value for 5. When asked for any element but the first two (here indexed as a sub 0 and a sub 1) it adds the preceding two elements (those subtractions are to the indices of the sequence, not the value). A sub zero is set to 0 and a sub one to 1.